# Is SimpleDateFormat in Java and Android different?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, jvm

1. When we call `parseJavaAndroid("2018-04-27T22:31:07.962-05:00")` from JVM it gives `ParseException` while a call from Emulator/Android Real device it works fine.
2. When we change `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ", Locale.ENGLISH)` to `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH)` in Android, it throws:

   > IllegalArgumentException with message "Unknown pattern character 'X' method".

   It works fine in JVM and gives `ParseException` in Emulator/Android Real device.

```java
public static Date parseJavaAndroid(String fromDate){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date=null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(fromDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

What should have to do then it works in both JVM and android real time device(**minSdkVersion:19**). I want pattern for "2018-04-27T22:31:07.962-05:00" which **works on both Android as well as Java**.

Note: **The individual pattern is working**, so Please don't suggest for individuals.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: You are definitely working too hard. Take the advice in the [Answer by picit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49673544/642706) to use the *java.time* classes instead. So much easier to do this: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-04-27T22:31:07.962-05:00")` and be done with it. The legacy date-time classes really are a wretched mess.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell about Android, but in the JVM, the `Z` pattern recognizes only offsets without `:`, such as `-0500`, while the `X` pattern can recognize `-05:00`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Perhaps Android has a different implementation, where `Z` also recognizes offsets with `:`, such as `-05:00`.

I'm afraid there's no one-pattern-fits-all solution: `Z` doesn't work in JVM, `X` doesn't work in Android, how to make it work in both? I think the best you can do is to try both patterns, something like this (in pseudocode):

```
try {
    parse with X
} catch(Exception e) {
    X didn't work, parse with Z
}
```

A **much better** alternative is to use the [threeten backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and configure with [ThreetenABP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) - or use [`java.time` classes](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html) if your API level is 26:

```
// parse input
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-04-27T22:31:07.962-05:00");

// convert to java.util.Date (threeten backport)
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(odt.toInstant());

// or, if you have java.time (API level 26)
Date date = date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Comment: There is no "X" in an Android below API 24.

Comment: One more reason to use the threeten backport. SimpleDateFormat is outdated and using the backport (or java.time, if available) is recommended. Anyway, another alternative is to try both patterns (`Z` and `X`) - this guarantees that it'll work in both environments

Comment: How to try both patterns z or x? Will you give that pattern?

Comment: Try one, catch the exception, try the other

Answer (score 0):

And according to your example and the [android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone), you should use `X` (ISO8601) instead of `Z`(RFC822)

That gives: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`

Comment: As mentioned in point 2. Add "X" in pattern gives IllegalArgumentException with message "Unknown pattern character 'X'" in Emulator/Android Real device.