# Comparing time is incorrect when picking 12:00

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I am creating a booking system and I don't want to allow users to book with starting time 11:00 and end time 09:00 (past)(I am using 24hour clock).
I have two combo boxes filled with Strings that act as start and end time (09:00,10:00,11:00,12:00,13:00....)

I have this code:

```
 String start = (String) startTime.getSelectedItem();
        String end = (String) endTime.getSelectedItem();
        try {
            if(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").parse(start).before(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").parse(end))){
                System.out.println("test1");// future date - good

            }else{
                System.out.println("fail2");// old date - bad
            }
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
                System.out.println("error");
        }
```

This works perfectly except when I pick start/end time to be 12:00. Program outputs opposite of what it is supposed to output and I am unsure why.

If I pick start time 14:00 and end time 12:00 the program will output fail2(good output),

If I pick start time 09:00 and end time 12:00 the program will output fail2(should be test1),

if I pick start time 12:00 and end time 10:00 the program will output test1(should be fail2),

if I pick start time 12:00 and end time 15:00 the program will output test1(good output)

This type of problem only occurs when I pick 12:00..

Comment: I think your format needs to be `HH:mm` because `hh` refers to a 12-hour clock https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Consider using `LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(start);` for your times.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Bonus points: As @notyou says, you won’t need an explicit formatter. And even if you did use a `DateTimeFormatter`, it would have notified you of your incorrect format pattern use through an exception.

Comment: Thank you guys for tips, I have to check this LocalTime out.

Comment: @OleV.V. upvoted but I meant on the old question you linked obviously.... TT_TT

Comment: Of course you meant that, @tatsu, sorry I misunderstood. Your call makes much better sense now. I have provided an answer to the linked question too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [12:xx shown as 00:xx in SimpleDateFormat.format(“hh:mm:ss”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708445/12xx-shown-as-00xx-in-simpledateformat-formathhmmss).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void checkTimes(String start, String end) {
    try {
        if (LocalTime.parse(start).isBefore(LocalTime.parse(end))) {
            System.out.println("test1");// future date - good
        } else {
            System.out.println("fail2");// old date - bad
        }
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Let’s try it:

```
    checkTimes("14:00", "12:00");
    checkTimes("09:00", "12:00");
    checkTimes("12:00", "10:00");
    checkTimes("12:00", "15:00");
```

This prints:

```
fail2
test1
fail2
test1
```

I believe this agrees with what you had intended. Note that `LocalTime` parses your strings without the need for an explicit formatter. Furthermore, if you trust that your combobox only contains valid time strings, you can leave out the `try`-`catch` construct since `DateTimeParseException` is an unchecked exception.

If `startTime` and `endTime` are `JComboBox`, I believe you can even fill `LocalTime` objects into them. Then you don’t need to parse when the user selects one from each. Your `JComboBox` will call `LocalTime.toString()`, which will return a string like `09:00`, which in turn the combo box will display and let the user select.

```
    LocalTime[] times = { LocalTime.of(9, 0), LocalTime.of(10, 0), LocalTime.of(11, 0), 
                          LocalTime.of(12, 0), LocalTime.of(13, 0), LocalTime.of(14, 0) };
    JComboBox<LocalTime> combo = new JComboBox<>(times);
```

[image: Combo]

Unfolded:

[image: Combobox unfolded]

I am using `LocalTime` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. `java.time` is generally much nicer to work with than the old and outdated date and time classes like `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and more.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: This is a far better solution than one that can't support booking intervals that span midnight.  Disallowing spanning midnight makes it much more complicated to support users from any time zone.  The question is what do you really want: to compare *numbers* or to compare *times*?  This is the solution that actually compares *times* rather than relatively arbitrary numbers that happen to represent portions of the time.  (That arbitrariness is part of why your original solution didn't work.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this great explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `HH:mm`.

`hh` ranges `01-12`, while `HH` ranges `1-23`.

### Update

Check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of `SimpleDateFormat`:

> H: Hour in day (0-23)
>
> h: Hour in am/pm (1-12)

Comment: This answer solves the issue too. Thank you @user6690200

Comment: @hDDen I have to remind you, in your answer, you are using `HH`... While in your question, it is `hh`

Comment: I didnt know before that this makes a difference, now I know. Thank you again.

Comment: @hDDen No problem :)

Comment: This answer points out why your implementation fails, for practical purposes isn't the best solution as it disallows intervals that span midnight.  It's a great answer to your question, but is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
String start = (String) startTime.getSelectedItem();
        String end = (String) endTime.getSelectedItem();
        SimpleDateFormat timer = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        try {
            Date startD = timer.parse(start);
            Date endD = timer.parse(end);
            if(startD.before(endD)){
                System.out.println("test1");// future date - good
            }else{
                System.out.println("fail2");// old date - bad
            }
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
                System.out.println("error");
    }
```

Changing my code to this fixed this issue..

Comment: No, @user6690200 's answer is the correct explanation.

Comment: @andy Would it be possible that there are two answers providing the correct answer? And both of them using the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class, BTW. Thank you anyway, hDDen, for providing your solution for us all.

Comment: @OleV.V. This answer is actually using `HH`, just like I posted. So they are basiclly the same one.

Comment: @hDDen you first wrote that usage of two SimpleDateFormat instances solved the issue. I think you have deleted this sentence. That was what I was referring to. The solution is „HH:mm“ instead. So your answer is correct now. (Ignoring the fact of outdatedness of SimpleDateFormat)