# Confusions about Java's Date class and getTime() function

Tags: java, date

I am new to Java's Date class. When I try to use its getTime() function for calculating time difference, issues come out. For example, below is the code.

```
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

            task = opt.get();
            task.setEndDate(dateFormat.format(date));

            Date startDate = null;
            try {
                startDate = dateFormat.parse(task.getStartDate());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("date parsing error...");
                startDate = date;
            }

            System.out.printf("Start date is: %s", task.getStartDate());
            System.out.printf("Start date is: %d", startDate.getTime());
            System.out.printf("End date is: %s", task.getEndDate());
            System.out.printf("End date is: %d", date.getTime());

            long diff = date.getTime() - startDate.getTime() - 43200000;
            System.out.printf("Time difference is: %d", diff);
            int secNum = (int)(diff / 1000);

            String timeCost = String.valueOf(secNum);
            System.out.println("Time cost(sec) is:");
            System.out.println(timeCost);
            task.setTimeCost(timeCost);
```

The outputs are:

```
Start date is: 2020-04-15 01:46:17
Start date is: 1586929577000
End date is: 2020-04-15 01:46:35
End date is: 1586972795461
Time difference is: 18461
Time cost(sec) is:18
```

As you might notice, there is 12 hours(43200000 ms) offset between the calculated difference and the real difference through "date.getTime() - startDate.getTime()".

I don't know what's going on. 
Does anyone have an idea and correct me ?

Comment: FYI, java.util.Date is extremely old and known to have usability issues.  If you can use Java 8 or above, the `java.time` package is recommended.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I find it difficult to understand your code without being able to run it. Could you please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I certainly agree with the others that you should not use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `Instant` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Your error could never have happened with java.time. Trust me.

Comment: Related: [12:xx shown as 00:xx in SimpleDateFormat.format(“hh:mm:ss”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708445/12xx-shown-as-00xx-in-simpledateformat-formathhmmss)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are storing the date/time as a string in your `task` object, and converting between Date and String using the format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`.  I believe lower-case `h` means you are using a 12-hour clock, but you do not include an AM/PM indicator in your format string.

I'm guessing you ran the code at 1:46 PM to produce the sample output.

You have "2020-04-15 01:46:17" stored as your start date. When you convert that back to a date, the formatter doesn't know whether it is an AM time or PM time.  I guess that it defaults to AM.

The Date object, however, knows that it was initialized with a PM time.  Therefore, when you subtract the two, you get over 12 hours difference, because it is subtracting 1:46:17 AM from 1:46:35 PM.

A simple recommendation would be to add an AM/PM indicator to your date format, or use a 24-hour clock (upper-case `H` in the format string).

An even better recommendation would be to **store dates as dates, not as strings!**  Convert them to strings when you want to display them.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `hh` which is a 12-hour hour format, hence `20:00` becomes `08:00`. You should use `HH` which is a 24-hour format. The below illustrates the difference.

```
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = new Date(1586973600000L);
        System.out.println(date);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        String fd1 = df.format(date);
        System.out.println(fd1);
        System.out.println(df.parse(fd1));

        df.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String fd2 = df.format(date);
        System.out.println(fd2);
        System.out.println(df.parse(fd2));
```

Also, `java.util.Date` is old, buggy and generally avoided for some time now. You might want to switch to `java.time` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

> I am new to Java's Date class.

Stop! Backup, rewind.

Both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` classes are *terrible*, deeply flawed, and quite frustrating. **Never use these classes.**

These classes were shipped in the earliest versions of Java. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

---

> `Date date = new Date();`

To capture the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), use [`Instant.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now()). Uses a resolution finer than the milliseconds used in the `java.util.Date` class it replaced.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

---

> `task.setEndDate(dateFormat.format(date));`

Your `Task` class should hold a *java.time* object rather than a mere string.

```
class Task {
    Instant start , stop ;
    …
}
```

Use smart objects rather than dumb strings throughout your Java codebase. Doing so ensures [valid values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation), provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

If your `Task` is like booking appointments in the future, where you want a certain time-of-day regardless of changes to the offset used by your time zone, then use `LocalDateTime`. This type represents only a date and time-of-day but lacks any concept of time zone or offset.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.APRIL , 15 ) ;
Localtime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

When generating a calendar where you need a specific point on the timeline, then apply the relevant time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

The issue at stake here is the fact that politicians around the world have shown a predilection for changing the offset used by the time zone(s) of their jurisdiction. The politicians do so with surprising frequency. And they have done so with little or no forewarning.

When exchanging date-time values with other systems textually, then use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These formats are used by default in *java.time* when parsing/generating text. And for presentation to users, produce automatically localized strings using [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

---

> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

This format is incorrect if you are trying to record moments, specific points on the timeline. You must include an indication of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) and/or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) to track a moment.

For moments, use the ISO 8601 formats mentioned above. Used by default, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2020-01-23T01:23:45.123456789Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Adjust from UTC into the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate localized text.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nLijBH).

> zdt.toString(): 2020-01-22T20:23:45.123456789-05:00[America/Montreal]
>
> output: mercredi 22 janvier 2020 à 20 h 23 min 45 s heure normale de l’Est

---

> `long diff = date.getTime() - startDate.getTime() - 43200000;`

No need to do the math yourself. We have a class for that: [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

If you want a count of whole seconds across the entire span of time, call [`Duration::toSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toSeconds()).

```
long seconds = d.toSeconds() ;  // Entire duration in terms of whole seconds.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).