# How to convert format date "MMddhhmmss" to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"?

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

How to convert calendar date to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format.

```
protected String paymentDatetime (String transmissionDateTime){
    long transactionDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddhhmmss");
        Calendar nowDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        nowDate.setTime(now);

        Calendar transmissionDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        transmissionDate.setTime(df.parse(transmissionDateTime));
        transmissionDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, nowDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        transactionDateTime = transmissionDate.getTime().getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOGGER.error("cannot parse transmission date time : " + transmissionDateTime);
    }
    return sdf.format(transactionDateTime);
}
```

I want to get the value thrown by **String transmissionDateTime**, but in fact when I throw the value = 1707**1255**17 (in AM) will be convert to "2020-07-17 00:55:17". How to convert so that every 12.00 or 00.00 (12 o'clock) both AM and PM don't change?

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` is correct, but `"MMddhhmmss"` is wrong and should be `"MMddHHmmss"` using uppercase `HH`. Didn't you see the difference in case and wonder what that might do? You should read the documentation of `SimpleDateFormat` to learn what the difference between `HH` and `hh` is, so you never do that again. See also: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/5221149)

Comment: If I'm using uppercase HH, time is right but the date and month change, like this 2020-05-07 12:55:17. Likewise, when I threw 1707005517, the date and month also change

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Word usage: in Java programming *throw* usually means to throw an exception. A value is *given in* `transmissionDateTime`, and you *enter* or *pass* that value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [12:xx shown as 00:xx in SimpleDateFormat.format(“hh:mm:ss”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708445/12xx-shown-as-00xx-in-simpledateformat-formathhmmss)

Answer (score 2):

Do not handle dates and times as strings in your program. Handle and store them as proper date-time objects. When you take string input, parse it to a date-time object. Only when you need to give string output, format your date-time object into an appropriate string.

### java.time

I think that your parsing becomes clearer with java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I understand that the hour given in the string is hour of day, so 00 means 12 midnight and 12 means 12 noon.

```
    Year thisYear = Year.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("ddMMHHmmss")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, thisYear.getValue())
            .toFormatter();
    
    String transmissionDateTimeString = "1707125517";
    
    LocalDateTime transmissionDateTime
            = LocalDateTime.parse(transmissionDateTimeString, inputFormatter);
    
    System.out.println(transmissionDateTime);
```

Output when running today:

> 2020-07-17T12:55:17

**Formatting output**

I am showing you two options for formatting output as `2020-07-17 12:55:17`.

1. Use a formatter
2. Simply replace the `T` with a space

Use a formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String output = transmissionDateTime.format(outputFormatter);
```

Simply replace the `T`:

```
    String output = transmissionDateTime.toString().replace('T', ' ');
```

### What went wrong in your code?

Lower case `hh` in a format pattern string is for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12. This goes for both the old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat` and for the modern `DateTimeFormatter`. You didn’t tell the formatter whether you wanted AM or PM. In this case `SimpleDateFormat` assumes AM, which is why you got a time og 00:55:17. Upper case `HH` is for hour of day from 00 through 23.

It furthermore seems that you have accidentally swapped month and day of month in your format pattern for parsing, `MMddhhmmss`. When I called your method, I got `2020-05-07 00:55:17`. Month and day of month are wrong. Your `df` parsed `1707125517` into `Fri May 07 00:55:17 CET 1971`. There is no 17th month of the year, but `SimpleDateFormat` confusingly extrapolates, so the 17th month of 1970 becomes the 5th month of 1971.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Similar questions:

  - [12:xx shown as 00:xx in SimpleDateFormat.format(“hh:mm:ss”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708445/12xx-shown-as-00xx-in-simpledateformat-formathhmmss)
  - [Difference between java HH:mm and hh:mm on SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat)

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` are old classes and no longer recommended. 
Use the [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

```
DateTimeFormatter from = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddhhmmss");
DateTimeFormatter to12Hour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
DateTimeFormatter to24Hour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(ldt.format(from));
System.out.println(ldt.format(to12Hour));
System.out.println(ldt.format(to24Hour));
```

Prints

```
0716082236
2020-07-16 08:22:36 PM
2020-07-16 20:22:36
```

Comment: This answer doesn't show anything related to converting the input string `"1707125517"` to output string `"2020-07-17 12:55:17"`, so it is rather *useless*.

Answer (score 0):

As already covered by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945127/how-to-convert-format-date-mmddhhmmss-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss/62945607#comment111311857_62945127): `MMddhhmmss` should be `MMddHHmmss` using uppercase `HH`.

---

String `"1707125517"` with format `MMddHHmmss` means `MM = 17` and `dd = 07`. When parsed without a year, the year defaults to 1970, and month 17 of the year 1970 resolves to month **5** of the year 1971, which is why the question code results in `2020-05-07` (month 5, day 7).

Are you sure the input with Month = 17 is what you want to parse, and that the format pattern is what you intended? Seems that month and day are flipped, given you said *"will be convert to "2020-07-17 00:55:17""*, where month is 7 and day is 17, so perhaps you should **try format `ddMMHHmmss` instead**.

The method in the question can be shortened to use only one `Calendar` object instead of two:

```java
protected static String paymentDatetime(String dateTime) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    try {
        cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMHHmmss").parse(dateTime));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date string: " + dateTime, e);
    }
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());
}
```

The method was also changed to **not ignore parsing exception**.

---

The old antiquated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes should not be used. Instead, use the newer **Java 8 Time API** classes.

```java
protected static String paymentDatetime(String dateTime) {
    DateTimeFormatter in = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("ddMMHHmmss")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, Year.now().getValue())
            .toFormatter();
    DateTimeFormatter out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, in).format(out);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm so sorry. I'm not thorough, the input which I want to parse is reverse. Thank you for your help and exposure