# Cannot change AM/PM of Time After 12:00 (AfterNoon)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time, simpledateformat

How do i convert 24 hours format to 12 hours along with AM/PM, i have checked articles and also in stackoverflow but problem is if string is "12:43" (afternoon time) and i converted it into 12 hours then it shows "12:43 AM" but it should show "12:43 PM". Below is the java code which i have written.

> MainActivity.Java

```
public class PrayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView result;
String fetch="12:43"
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
result=findViewById(R.id.result);
Date dateCode = null;
String formatTwelve;
String resultsAfter;
final SimpleDateFormat code12Hours = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                            try {
                                dateCode = code12Hours.parse(fetch);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
formatTwelve = code12Hours.format(dateCode);
if (formatTwelve.equals(fetch)) {
                                resultsAfter= formatTwelve + " AM";
                            } else {
                                resultsAfter= formatTwelve + " PM";
                            }
result.setText(resultsAfter);
}}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` or can you switch to `java.time`? Would be easier and less error-prone.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Related: [12:xx shown as 00:xx in SimpleDateFormat.format(“hh:mm:ss”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708445/12xx-shown-as-00xx-in-simpledateformat-formathhmmss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] stringDates = { "12:43", "14:00", "10:00" };
        for (String dateString : stringDates) {
            // Input 24 HRS
            LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH));

            // Output 12 hrs
            System.out.println(localTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)));
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
12:43 PM
02:00 PM
10:00 AM
```

Comment: If the `String myDateString="14:00"` then it is showing 14:00 PM, It should show "2:00PM"

Comment: @SOUGATRIYADH  You can accept it again if u think its what u want :)

Comment: @Hades - I have edited your answer for a couple of things: (1) `throws ParseException` is not required. It seems that you first tried it with `SimpleDateFormat` and missed to remove it when you did it finally with `DateTimeFormatter` (2) You should always use `Locale` with `DateTimeFormatter` to avoid string being printed using JVM's default `Locale`.

Comment: @Hades I have a one problem is that if i use `LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH));` then in previous android versions like 7.0, 7.1 it is getting crashed and the error is pointing on this line. The error is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter"

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is use `"h:mm a"` or `"hh:mm aa"` for more details or code you can follow this [gist](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Date-Picker-Example-/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/muhammadatif/datepicker/dateexample/utilities/Tools.java) link for better understanding.

```
try {
    String timeLong = "2020-10-08 06:06:30";
    String timeShort = "16:06 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat formatLong = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat formatShort = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.US);
    Log.v("out", formatShort.format(formatLong.parse(timeLong)));
    Log.v("out", formatShort.format(formatShort.parse(timeShort)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output :
06:06 AM
04:06 PM

Comment: It is crashing if i use this.

Comment: I use this code `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
                            String strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
String time = "12:43";
try {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
     Date dateObj = sdf.parse(time);
    System.out.println(dateObj);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm").format(dateObj));
} catch (final ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}` and the result is "0:43" not showing AM/PM. It should show 12:43 PM

Comment: have a look at "HH:mm:ss aa"

Comment: still same problem.